# Directory name for non-generic Proprietary stuff

Tags: directory

Is there a common or standard directory name for the company-specific stuff that exists in a server? This would include any crons, scripts, webserver docroots, programs, non-database storage areas, service codebases, etc.

We could of course put crons in /etc/cron.d, put docroots in /home/webservd, scripts in one of the bin directories, but that would be messy. If XYZ Technology Corp wanted to have all the non-generic stuff in one place, would they make a directory /xyz or /home/xyz or is there an alternative directory name that is not company-specific, but intended for company-specific stuff?

What is most common?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as a ZFS user, oddly enough I'm going with

`/tank` for the ZFS Volume that is mounted. Naming convention coined in documentation..

`/tin` for `/dev/vda` root device (not ZFS) This way they are right next to each other alphabetically.

Before that I was using `/700s` (or other company name) and putting *everything* under there, but again that was a company name; not generic.

Answer (score 4):

No, there are absolutely no standards for naming conventions beyond that which is provided by your OS vendor (or the FHS, for some subset of Linux distributions).

Whatever you decide to go with, just make a decision, document it well in all the possible places people might need to look for it, and then get back to doing useful work.  Directory hierarchies are classic bike shed/holy war territory, and the only way to stop the battles once they start is to ask the combatants for input into your new whole-company coding standards...

Answer (score 2):

The only standard I'm aware of that even comes close is using /opt or /usr/local for apps installed manually vs. the platform's package manager.  Even then, there are lots of apps that ignore this standard.

Answer (score 2):

The unix tradition is to keep your stuff in an appropriately named subdir of /opt/ or /usr/local/. The usual best practice uses symlinks in /etc/* and other system areas that map back to a smaller number of company-admin directories where you keep and edit the 'real' copies. (or vice versa for those few cases where the real file can't be in userland)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Stow is an example of a similar scheme.

Answer (score 2):

The specific answer for your operating system can usually be found in the `hier` manual page (run `man hier` at any shell prompt).